# Shapeless not working in generic context

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I am still trying to get my head around Shapeless (and, to a lesser extent, Scala!) and I have been writing some simple code to generate random instance data for case classes - predominantly based on the guides here: http://enear.github.io/2016/09/27/bits-of-shapeless-2/ (the example covers a JSON Writer implementation)

I have created a `Generator[A]` trait and created implicit implementations for simple types, and as per the example in the above link, I have also created implicit implementations to handle HList, HNil, Coproduct and CNil:

```
  implicit def hnilGenerator = new Generator[HNil] {
    override def generate(a: HNil) = HNil
  }

  implicit def hconsGenerator[H, T <: HList](implicit headGen: Generator[H], tailGen: Generator[T]) =
    new Generator[H :: T] {
      override def generate(a: H :: T) = headGen.generate(a.head) :: tailGen.generate(a.tail)
    }

  implicit def cnilGenerator: Generator[CNil] =
    new Generator[CNil] {
      override def generate(a: CNil): CNil = throw new RuntimeException("Invalid candidate configuration")
    }

  implicit def cconsGenerator[H, T <: Coproduct] =
    new Generator[H :+: T] {
      override def generate(a: H :+: T) = throw new RuntimeException("Invalid candidate configuration")
    }
```

I can now use this code to generate a random instance based on a case class or a sealed trait:

```
    it("should work with a case class to hlist") {
      case class Test(x: IntGene, y: DoubleGene, z: BooleanGene)
      val c = Generic[Test].to(Test(IntGene(), DoubleGene(), BooleanGene()))
      generate(c)
    }
    it("what happens with sealed traits") {
      sealed trait Shape
      case class Square(width: Int, height: Int) extends Shape
      case class Circle(radius: Int) extends Shape

      val c = Generic[Shape].to(Circle(1))
      generate(c)
    }
```

Both of the above work no problem, however, if I try to make this a generic (as in parameter types) I get compilation errors not being able to find the necessary implicts:

```
it("should handle generics") {
  case class GenericTest[A: Generic](x: A) {
    def convert() = {
      val c = Generic[A].to(x)
      generate(c)
    }
  }
}
```

So from my understanding, because I have used the `Generic` context bound `A`, the compiler knows that is going to be available, so `c` must be some possible return from the call `to(x)` - Am I missing something in the implementation to handle that return type from the `Generic` shapeless call? Or have I wildly misunderstood something?

I am hoping this is possible and I have just missed something - is it that the compiler doesn't know what will be passed in (Im assuming not), or is there another possible type that needs to be handled implicitly from that `to(x)` call?

---

**EDIT**

Compile error added below - I'm really just trying to understand: Is it that there is some return case from the `to(x)` shapeless call that I have not catered for, or is it because the compiler doesn't have any idea what will be passed in and there are some types not catered for (e.g. I haven't added a Date generator implicit - and a case class could potentially have any type included? I was hoping that was not the case, and as the compiler knows nothing is actually being passed to the class/method it knows there are no issues?)

```
GeneratorSpec.scala:44: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: io.github.robhinds.genotype.Generator[GenericTest.this.evidence$1.Repr]
          generate(c)
```

And my generate method is just a simple helper method that gets given the implicit `Generator` :

```
def generate[A](a: A)(implicit gen: Generator[A]) = gen.generate(a)
```

Comment: Why do you need a value to generate another one? About your question, have you taken a look at `shapeless.TypeClassCompanion`, which is meant to deal with typeclasses for ADT?

Comment: pasting your compilation error might be useful.

Comment: probably type inference breaks somewhere in your code and you might want to help Scalac a bit.

Comment: also, what is the type signature of `generate()`?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet no real reason - I was playing with the idea of passing in other configuration with the object (to provide constraints for the generated values, max/mins etc) - but like i said really its just for fun :).  Thanks - will take a look at that TypeClassCompanion code

Comment: @marios I have added the compile error and generate signature - Im really just trying to get my head around what is going on!

Comment: By the way, there is a possible simple implementation for `:+:` case, if you want to generate a value for the same type that your input is: `def generate(a: H :+: T) = a.eliminate(h => Inl[H, T](H.generate(h)), t => Inr[H, T](T.generate(t)))`

Comment: Thanks @CyrilleCorpet I will try adding that solution in too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `Generic` ***only*** converts a case class to a `HList` and a sealed trait to a `Coproduct` (not recursively).

So if you have a generic `Generic`, you have no information on what `HList` or `Coproduct` you are given, so, you cannot use your product and coproduct rules to find the wanted implicit. In some explicit case, you might have the same problem, so I will give you this as an example:

Let's say you have a case class architecture

```
case class Bottom(value: String)
case class Top(bot: Bottom, count: Int)
```

The implicit `Generic[Top]` will have `type MyHList = Bottom :: Int :: HNil` as output type, so you'll be asking for an implicit `Generator[MyHList]`. But since you don't have an implicit `Generator[Bottom]` in scope, you won't be able to use `hconsgenerator`.

In the generic case, it's even worse. The compiler can only infer `HList` for the output type of `Generic[A]` (and that's assuming you forget about `Coproduct`), so you need an implicit `Generator[HList]`, which you cannot provide.

The solution is to give an implicit for constructs that have a generic that can itself be generated:

```
implicit def generic2generate[T, L <: HList](implicit generic: Generic.Aux[T, L], lGen: Generator[L]): Generator[T] = new Generator[T] {
  def generate(c: T) = generic.from(lGen.generate(generic.to(c)))
}
```

**EDIT**

You can now follow the implicit resolution for our `Top` type:

- We can have a `Generator[Top]` using last rule, if we have a `Generic.Aux[Top, L]` for some `L`, and a `Generator[L]`.
- The only `Generic.Aux[Top, _]` that exists implicitly is a `Generic.Aux[Top, Bottom :: Int :: HNil]`, so we are reduced to finding a `Generator[Top, Bottom :: Int :: HNil]`
- using the hcons rule three times, we are reduced to finding a `Generator[Bottom]`, a `Generator[Int]` and a `Generator[HNil]`.
- `Generator[Int]` is given (I assume) and `Generator[HNil]` is the first rule, so we are reduced to finding a `Generator[Bottom]`
- the only rule that can provide one, is once again the 3rd rule, so we must find a `Generator[String :: HNil]`, since the only `Generic` available is a `Generic.Aux[Bottom, String :: HNil]`.
- using the hcons rule, we are down to finding a `Generator[String]`, which can easily be provided.

This example shows different points:

- first that it may take a long time when compiling to solve all these implicits (I only gave the main points of the proof, but the compiler has to try all possible branches)
- second, that this resolution can only be done for a **specific** `Generic`, it cannot be inferred **generically** (although this might seem counter-intuitive); even if the human mind is able to tell that it will work for **every** `Generic`, the compiler cannot process it as such.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will take a look at adding this - I did briefly consider that I might have to handle this case (tbh, the original link alludes to it, but I think  I got it wrong in the translation to my problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the Generator type bound.

```
it("should handle generics") {
  case class GenericTest[A: Generic : Generator](x: A) {
    def convert() = {
      val c = Generic[A].to(x)
      generate(c)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `A` does not need to have the `Generator` typeclass (since it should be inferred from `Generic`), but rather its generic representation: `case class GenericTest[A, Repr: Generator](x: A)(implicit val gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr])`